# Docusign rate limit to receive documents in 1 envelope

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I am trying to switch to the production API of Docusign. When I submit the required 20 envelopes for approval they do not get approved. I recieved a log file that lists multiple `GET` requests. It violates the API rules, only one `GET` request per envelope per 15 minutes is allowed according to the documentation. (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits)
When I list my envelope and loop through the envelope multiple times to get the documents out of it. I do multiple `GET` requests to the same envelope and that's why I think I get a rate limit error.

In the example below, you can see that when I retrieve the envelope, I immediately loop over the documents inside the envelope and get the documents with the `getDucument` method as described in the documentation. (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/get-an-envelope-document-list)

```
public function getEnvelopeDocument ($envelopeId) 
    {
        $documents = $this->envelopeApi->listDocuments(config('docusign.id'), $envelopeId);
        try {
            foreach($documents->getEnvelopeDocuments() as $document)
            {
                $docs[] =  $this->envelopeApi->getDocument((config('docusign.id')), $document->getDocumentId(), $envelopeId);
            }
        } catch (ApiException $e){
            dd("Error connecting Docusign : " . $e->getResponseBody()->errorCode . " " . $e->getResponseBody()->message);
        }
    }
```

Am I violating the API rate limiter? If so, what would be the allowed way to retrieve documents inside an envelope.

Comment: Drew's answer is correct, the way the API rules are enforced is that you cannot make a GET request to the same (exact) envelope endpoint more than once every 15 mins.  Since your documents each have a different document ID each one of those requests is a GET request to a new resource, not one that you have already requested.  Therefore, I would examine your additional calls to see if there are other potential rule violations.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of the code is that you are performing the following calls in sequence:

`GET /envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents` - ListDocuments

`GET /envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/1` - get document 1

`GET /envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/2` - get document 2

and so on.

If this is the case, you are not in violation of the API limit. If you were to make two calls to the ListDocuments or to one of the individual documents within 15 minutes that would be a polling violation.

To confirm everything is acceptable, you might capture API logs to confirm you're hitting each unique endpoint only once. Info on API logs is available here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging